# UnicodeDecodeError in extended template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have base.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>{% block head.title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block body.content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>

</html>
```

and 500.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head.title %}
    500 ł
{% endblock %}

{% block body.content %}
    500 - 
{% endblock %}
```

When I generate some error I don`t see 500 ł but

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 54: unexpected code byte
```

When I change ł to l everything is fine. I creates new html files with eclipse. What is wrong?

EDIT:

I cannot use any of polish diactric characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your template file might not being saved in utf8 by Eclipse. According to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108668) it chooses your OS's default encoding, which may not be utf8.

You can configure Eclipse like [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eruinf/v2r1m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iru.doc/concepts/cirerwp.htm):

- Set the global text file encoding preference Workbench > Editors to "UTF-8".
- If an encoding other than UTF-8 is required, set the encoding on the individual file rather than using the global preference setting. To do this use the File > Properties > Info menu selection to set the encoding on an individual file.

Or you can use the HTML entity which is `&#321;` and then it doesn't matter what encoding the file is saved as.

Answer (score 0):

ł is not a valid utf8 character, you will have to replace it with it's ascii character reference `&#321;`

[This website](http://bokehman.com/characters) has a useful list of ascii codes for any special characters you want to include in your web pages.

Comment: I cannot use any of polish diactric characters. I think that utf supports polish language, so maybe a problem is somewhere else?